# Issue with Forest road Designer plugin in QGIS 2.18.28

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, numpy

I have both QGIS 2.18.28 and QGIS 3.14.1 on my PC. Forest Road Designer works only on QGIS 2.18.28 version. I am trying to use this plugin, but I got an Error message.
What the problem is? I have used it before.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggest you do, if you need this plugin?

Comment: looks like you need to install numpy

Comment: I am not sure how?

Comment: Which of this:  numpy-1.19.1+mkl-cp39-cp39-win_amd64, I have to use? I have 64 bit machine, and this forest road plugin use Python27, I think